# Signed/unsigned int array type matching in C# switch expressions in generic methods

Tags: c#

I'm a little confused about how switch expression pattern matching works in C# with generics.

In the code below I have a generic method `Bar` taking an array parameter. To determine the type of the array I use a switch expression with specific branches for `int[]` and `uint[]`. I would expect that if the array I pass into `Bar()` from `Foo()` is type `int[]` then it would match the `int[]` branch in the switch expression, and if it is of type `uint[]` then it would match the `uint[]` branch. However, that doesn't happen. Whichever type I pass in matches whichever branch comes first.

```cs
        public void Foo()
        {
            Bar(new int[] {1, 2, int.MinValue});
            Bar(new uint[] {1, 2, uint.MaxValue});
        }

        private void Bar<T>(T[] array)
        {
            var text =
                array switch
                {
                    int[] values => $"Signed ints: {string.Join(',', values)}",
                    uint[] values => $"Unsigned ints: {string.Join(',', values)}",
                    _ => "Neither"
                };

            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
```

The output of this is:

```
Signed ints: 1,2,-2147483648
Signed ints: 1,2,-1
```

If I put the `uint[]` branch first then it shows that branch's output instead for both types of array. And if I use explicit types instead of generics then it just won't compile.

I may be missing something but this seems wrong. Am I missing something?

[This is using .NET Core SDK 3.1.403.]

Comment: [See this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/20874)

Comment: Thank you @canton7. I tried looking for an issue in GitHub but obviously wasn't looking hard enough. So, it seems that in such cases I can't rely on a switch expression to differentiate.

Comment: Note that you cannot rely on `is` either, it has the same behaviour.

Comment: @JosHickson No problem, it helps that I'd come across it before and knew what to search for!

Comment: added an answer, but was wrong, no is does not do it either